# C++ Making a function for reading in a .txt file and checking to make sure the file exists, but my loop isn't working

Tags: c++, file, loops, ifstream

I'm trying to make a function to read in a file, check to make sure it exists (and if it doesn't ask for the filename again), and then print "Loading..." if it DOES find the file.

However, the loop only goes through once. It prints out "FILE ERROR: File does not exist!" and then ends the program. Any ideas? Tell me if you need more information!

```
void find_board(string fileName)
{
bool filefound = 0;
ifstream in_stream;

do
{
    cout << "Enter the name of the file containing the board: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    in_stream.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
        filefound = 0;
        cout << "FILE ERROR: File does not exist!" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        filefound = 1;
    }
} while (filefound == 0);

cout << endl << "Loading..." << endl;

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);` for?

Comment: lol, as soon as I read your response I was like "omg". I didn't even realize I had an exit statement in there, thank you so much! I'll mark your response as solved as soon as it let's me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here I see is with the line:

exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

If you want to loop after a none existing file name - you need to remove this line!

Comment: I figured it out, I can't believe I left that line of code in there! Thank you so much for the help though!